# SELECT a variable as condition and display another one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

My problem is the following.

I want to `SELECT` the minimum of a years list and display another row of my table.

An example:

```
SELECT MIN(Year) 
FROM table     -> Searching for the lowest year.
```

and then I want it to display the `Winners` of the first year.

Is there a way to do this in just one line?

Comment: Yes, but you have to share more information about your table structure and sample data.

Comment: And by the way, you can put any select in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select winner from table where year in (select min(year) from table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a self-JOIN between table and itself (I suppose you want to do it in a single *statement*, not a single *line*):

```
SELECT A.*
    FROM table AS A
    JOIN ( SELECT MIN(Year) AS Year FROM table ) AS B
    ON (A.Year = B.Year);
```

This assumes that there is only one record per minimum-year in every group of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
select t.columntoshow, min(t.year) from table t group by t.columntoshow
```